# How to send a message when the user is leaving the page using SignalR?

Tags: websocket, signalr

I'm working on a chat room program using ASP.NET, I have made a *'user has joined the chatroom'* message, but how would I send a message when the user leaves the page? I tried looking through the network logs, but I can't see any extra messages getting sent through the WebSocket.

[image: Logs]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I've found out about `window.onbeforeunload` using JavaScript. Though it's not 100% consistent, it's more consistent than I expected.

Answer (score 1):

This will be tough and inaccurate because there is really no guarantee that you will get notified that the user has disconnected. But there is an onDisconnect event that you can listen for, but in all honesty, I would use a disconnect button and use that to do what you need to do, it would be more consistent, as the disconnect is not reliable (at least the last time I used SignalR, which was like version 1.x)